# I have an Issue trying to export a service in AngularJs, saying Unknown provider: loginServiceProvider <- loginService <- LoginController

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, webpack

I am trying to learn AngularJs in 2021. I know. When I try to use the service to login in my app, I get this message: Unknown provider: loginServiceProvider <- loginService <- LoginController.

I tried following the Documentation, but the build used by the company I am trying to work for, uses webpack and NodeJS, and cannot quite find the rigth examples online.

This is the Controller:

```js
import angular from 'angular';
import template from './login.tpl.html';

function LoginController($scope,$location,loginService){
    loginService.ClearCredentials();
    $scope.login = function () {
        console.log("Hizo click")
        $scope.dataLoading = true;
        loginService.Login($scope.username, $scope.password, function(response) {
            if(response.success) {
                window.alert("success")
                loginService.SetCredentials($scope.username, $scope.password);
                $location.path('/');
            } else {
                window.alert("success")
                $scope.error = response.message;
                $scope.dataLoading = false;
            }
        });
    };
}

LoginController.$inject=['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'loginService'];

export default angular
  .module('login.view', [])
  .controller('LoginController', LoginController)
  .component('login', {
    template,
  })
  .name
```

And this is the Service:

```js
import config from '../common/config';

export default {
  name: 'loginService',
  factory: ['$http', 'localStorage', ($http, localStorage) => {
    function Service($http, $localStorage) {
      var service = {};

      service.Login = Login;
      service.Logout = Logout;

      return service;

      function Login(username, password, callback) {
          $http.post('/api/authenticate', { username: username, password: password })
              .success(function (response) {
                  if (response.token) {
                      $localStorage.currentUser = { username: username, token: response.token }
                      $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + response.token;
                      callback(true);
                  } else {
                      callback(false);
                  }
              });
      }

      function Logout() {
          delete $localStorage.currentUser;
          $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = '';
      }
  }
  }]
}
```

I really would appreciate any help I could get.

Comment: How does the service registration into the angular dependecy injector looks like? Ex. `angular.service('loginService', LoginServiceClass)`

Answer (score 0):

The error you got means that the controller is not aware of the injected loginService, as if it doesn't exist in the bootstraped angularjs app. The exported service should be assigned to a module before you can inject it. So in your case I think you should add `.service('loginService', loginService)` as follows:

```js
export default angular
  .module('login.view', [])
  .controller('LoginController', LoginController)
  .service('loginService', loginService)
  .component('login', {
    template,
  })
  .name
```

don't forget to import the service in the controller file so you can use the exported service.
`import loginService from './path-of-your-service-file'`